# Nvidia graphics card not detected, using 'lspci | grep VGA' it only shows intel device. Is this hardware issue or OS level problem?

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, docker, nvidia-geforce

[image: output-of-lspci | grep VGA]

We have procured multiple servers from the vendor, I'm trying to find Nvidia GPU details from one of the servers and there is an issue with the server where it is not detecting the Nvidia graphics card but the other server that we have procured is working fine.

Upon searching for a GPU card using `lspci |grep VGA`, it detects only intel devices and not Nvidia cards. is this a hardware issue or an OS issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I assume it's more probably an hardware issue / bios configuration issue.